# Python TypeError: must be str, not Atom

Tags: python, oop, repr

Can someone tell me in beginner friendly way why am I not being able to print the Molecule name (here in this case 'NaCl') ?
if I replace `return Molecule([self, other])` with `return Molecule([self.label, other.label])` my code works and produces the expected output but I want to pass instances and not attributes. here is my code:

```
class Atom:
  def __init__(self, label):
    self.label = label

  def __add__(self, other):
    return Molecule([self, other])
    
class Molecule:
  def __init__(self, atoms):
    if type(atoms) is list:
        self.atoms = atoms
      
  def __repr__(self):
    lol = ''
    for i in self.atoms:
      lol += i
    return lol

sodium = Atom("Na")
chlorine = Atom("Cl")
salt = Molecule([sodium, chlorine])
salt = sodium + chlorine
print(salt)
```

here is the exercise image:
[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZbcF.png)

Comment: Please include the traceback in the question. See [mre] for reference

Comment: BTW, it's better practice to use `str.join()` instead of adding strings. It would also make `Molecule.__repr__` much simpler - just `return ''.join(self.atoms)`. Also BTW welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trace is telling you what line you need to look at.
Line 14 you have this

```
lol += i
```

Python is struggling with this cause first `lol` is a string. We know that cause you assigned it this with `lol = ''`

but now you're asking Python to append an instance of `Atom` to the str. However you haven't told Python how it's supposed to append a type of `Atom` to a str.

So you have two options here.

1. In your `Atom` class, override the `__repr__` function and then convert `i` to a string.
2. In your `Molecule` class, append to `lol` with `i.label` rather than just `i`

Answer (score 0):

Implement the`__repr__` function on your Atom class as well, and call it using `str(atom)`;

```
class Atom:
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Molecule([self, other])

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label

class Molecule:
    def __init__(self, atoms):
        if type(atoms) is list:
            self.atoms = atoms

    def __repr__(self):
        lol = ''
        for i in self.atoms:
            lol += str(i)
        return lol

sodium = Atom("Na")
chlorine = Atom("Cl")
salt = Molecule([sodium, chlorine])
salt = sodium + chlorine
print(salt)
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. it made me understand about " __repr__ " method a little bit more